# dm-crypt+LUKS performance and influence on RAM usage

Tags: memory, encryption, luks, dm-crypt

I'm using dm-crypt + LUKS to encrypt 3 partitions of my disc.

Recently I started wondering how does it influence my system..

I know that due to the decryption the boot time is longer, but I would like to know:

**How does this encryption influence my RAM?**

Is that were the whole decrypted stuff is stored?

Is there a better way of encrypting whole filesystem when my device has little RAM?

I'm working with embedded devices so every MB counts.

I have read cryptsetup README and FAQ briefly but I could not find answer to my questions.

I do not want to dive deep into the documentation.

Comment: You should have a budget of ca. 1G of RAM for the encryption to avoid I/O bottlenecks. On very small disks (8G or less) this can be cut to 512M. YMMV of course, but these are the empirical values, where dm-crypt overhead starts to become less noticable.